# How to install Azure Az - Cannot convert value "2.0.0-preview" to type "System.Version"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I get the following Exception when I try to install Azure Az with PowerShell:

[image: Powershell Exception]

PowerShell 5.1 and .NET is installed. All AzureRM, Azure and Azure Az Modules which where previously installed are now uninstalled.

I tried different versions, with clobber and without, with force and without and I also executed the commands in an admin powershell.
For example:

- Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber
- Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 2.0.0

I had Azure Az already installed on this computer but had to uninstall it. I uninstalled it with this [script by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-2.1.0#uninstall-the-az-module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade PowerShellGet to latest version by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/installing-psget. PowerShellGet with Version 1.0.0.1 could not recognize preview version string.

Answer (score 0):

Skimmed through script you used for cleanup and i am confused.

but this should fix issue. Check for all installed `AZ` module and manually remove them by deleting the folders from machine.  Once the are all gone try re-installing

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4rvJ.png]

10 out of 10 times that resolves my module issues.